# Сортировка объекта по вложенному массиву

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, объекты, lodash

```
[{
    skills: [{
        level: 22,
        name: "Anna",
    }, {
        level: 31,
        name: "Pasha"
    }, {
        level: 11,
        name: "Igor"
    }],
    id: "1"
}, {
    skills: [{
        level: 2,
        name: "Anna",
    }, {
        level: 35,
        name: "Pasha"
    }, {
        level: 335,
        name: "Igor"
    }],
    id: "2"
}, {
    skills: [{
        level: 101,
        name: "Anna",
    }, {
        level: 77,
        name: "Pasha"
    }, {
        level: 12,
        name: "Igor"
    }],
    id: "3"
}]
```

Допустим я хочу новый массив, который отсортирован по полю level, где name = "Anna". Как это сделать? Новый массив должен быть такой:

```
[, {
    skills: [{
        level: 101,
        name: "Anna",
    }, {
        level: 77,
        name: "Pasha"
    }, {
        level: 12,
        name: "Igor"
    }],
    id: "3"
}, {
    skills: [{
        level: 22,
        name: "Anna",
    }, {
        level: 31,
        name: "Pasha"
    }, {
        level: 11,
        name: "Igor"
    }],
    id: "1"
}, {
    skills: [{
        level: 2,
        name: "Anna",
    }, {
        level: 35,
        name: "Pasha"
    }, {
        level: 335,
        name: "Igor"
    }],
    id: "2"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const newArray = arr.slice(); // так как sort мутирует массив, а нужен новый
const isAnnaSkill = skill => skill.name === 'Anna';
const getAnnaLevel = item => item.skills.find(isAnnaSkill)?.level;
newArray.sort((a, b) => getAnnaLevel(b) - getAnnaLevel(a));
```

Comment: isAnnaSkill: Вы присваиваете значение объекту. Должно быть `skill.name === 'Anna'` P.s. всегда ли хорошо разбивать код на блок однострочек?) Всё это, выполненное внутри sort выглядело бы не хуже.